# How to get more information from Reporting Services about error: rsProcessingAborted?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

My company has recently added a new server for both our hosted applications and our database (Windows Server 2022 for both), an upgrade from our previous servers (Windows Server 2019 / 2012 R2). On the database servers we also host Reporting Services for reports.

After migrating our production application (2019 -> 2022) and the the database and Reporting Services (2012 R2 -> 2022), everything seemed to be working fine, with the production application hitting the database and Reporting Services for generating PDF's to download.

However, one issue remains, and that is the "Preview" feature of Reporting Services. Our web app offers users an option to "Preview" the report in the browser using RS's generic UI portal. When trying to use this feature, however, users get the message: "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)" with no further information. This error persists when pointing the original web application (2019) to the new Reporting Services database (2022). However, pointing the new server web application (2022) to the old Reporting Services database (2012 R2) gives the expected result of a previewed report in the browser. This tells us there isn't any problem with the application's code.

This is further confirmed when the production code is run from a local machine (Visual Studio 2022) on our in-house network and pointed at the new (2022) Reporting Services database: the report is previewed as expected, with no errors. In all instances, the report is still able to be generated into a PDF for download without error.

Thus my question is two-fold:

1. Is there a way to retrieve more information about this error? The log files on the new Reporting Service database (2022) aren't showing anything helpful or useful. The most recently updated log file, RSHosting, shows "2024-02-14 08:44:50.5552|INFO|9|Catalog max connection pool size: 100", but no errors of any kind. Another log file, the RSPortal, shows "2024-02-14 08:32:15.7037|INFO|104|Received request GET /api/v2.0/CatalogItems(Path='/[report-path]')| RequestID = s_710cbb81-4fff-4776-9ea5-7927d77baf5e" followed by "2024-02-14 08:32:15.7037|INFO|108|Sending response. Response code [app-user-requesting-report] 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0063338| RequestID = s_710cbb81-4fff-4776-9ea5-7927d77baf5e". Again, no errors, and this log file is only RS Portal related; no information about other connections to the api are listed. Is there another place where log files are kept?
2. Is there a potential compatibility issue that arises when upgrading Reporting Services from version 12 (old server, 2012 R2) to a newer version, v 16 (new server, 2022)? Again the web-application that access these different servers works as expected when running through VS2022 on a local machine in our in-house network. This same code displays the error when previewing the report, again running on our in-house network but from the newer server (2022).

Additional Information: The web-application in production is written in .NET Framework 4.7, and uses Reporting.Webforms library to access the RS, as well as RE2005 and RS2005 libraries. Settings for Reporting Services on the old and new servers are essentially the same aside from the URL (which is changed in the web-app when pointing from one to the other) and the service account (which has been allowed access). Furthermore, the web-portal for RS is accessible from the new web-application server (2022) and returns reports as expected in the browser. Neither RS server is using SSL.

Again to reiterate, the ONLY place report preview is not working is through our web-application when hosted on the new server running Windows 2022, when connecting to the new RS Server running Windows 2022. Every other configuration / instance allows the previewing of the reports.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Assuming that if you get the generated URL from your app and open it on your PC, the report displays correctly, then my next step would be to try this URL directly from the browser on the server hosting the web app (remote desktop etc.) If it fails there then it *might* be related to the datasource connection authentication, the account running the app may not have access to the the database. It's just guesswork, but I would start by trying to open the URL directly in the webapp server's browser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I went ahead and tried this and had the same result (error displaying when trying to preview). I went a step further and tried it from the web browser on the Report Server database, so essentially the same machine, and again, same error.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, that would suggest an authentication issue with the datasource. If you can, try temporarily setting the data source credentials (directly on the server via the web portal) to an account that you know has access to the database, to keep it simple, if the sql server supports it, use a sql login and try again.

Comment: I believe @AlanSchofield is correct, as we recently refreshed the server with the database on it and methodically went through the steps of setting credentials etc. We also updated the credentials in the data source via the web portal for report services and after all that, it works. Whoever set up the server / report server initially must have missed a step somewhere. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with a recent migration to a new set of servers, and what solved the problem for us was ensuring the web config file of our .NET application had the correct assemblies listed.

Since we were upgrading the Report Services server, we had to adjust the version number and public key token of any entries referring to ReportViewerControl.

In your web config file, look for these three locations:

```
<buildProviders>
<httpHandlers>
<handlers>
```

In each of these locations you should find a reference to the ReportViewerWebControl or RdlBuildProvider. Update the "version" number to the appropriate version (ours went to 15), and then update the PublicKeyToken for each as well. Ensure that all three match (we had a mismatch).

[This link from Microsoft was extremely helpful in getting the key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver16)

NOTE: in the "assemblies" section we also had 7 entries for the ReportViewer assemblies already updated to 15, referring to the nuget packages related to Report Server, so check that area as well.

Comment: Thanks, I did look into this but it unfortunately did not solve the problem.